# Фиксирования позиция бекграунда на телефонах

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

Суть проблемы - при скроллинге вверх\вниз, в мобильных браузерах меняется `viewport`(адресная строка выезжает\заезжает) и фиксированый бэкграунд странички ресайзиться. Проблема в том что пока скролл не закончиться, бекграунд не ресайзиться и внизу появляется белая область.

[Вот](https://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/progressive.php) пример. Речь идет только о мобильных браузерах.

Может знает кто как пофиксить? Хейт больший давать пробовал. Функции на ресайз до конца скрола не работает, а после скрола оно и само по себе ресайзиться. Нужно что бы во время скрола белая область не появлялась.
Спасибо!

Comment: Наверное как и мне, никому суть проблемы так и не стала ясна...

Comment: Я бы посоветовала отказаться от fixed хотя бы на мобильных, именно он вызывает изменение размеров фонового изображения. Вопрос в том, что для вас принципиальней: фиксированный фон или отсутствие неприятных артефактов на мобильных.